# not able to upload 360 video to youtube

Tags: virtual-reality, 360-panorama, theta360

I just bought my theta s 360 camera. I wanted to upload it into youtube. I followed a few tutorials. But it was unsuccessful. I have attached the screenshot of the video that was uploaded in youtube.

Thank you. [this is the screen shot of the video i had tried to upload and failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPZDm.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You should edit your video to make it 'spherical'. It would look more like this:[Panoramic Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1srnn.jpg)
A 360 image is generally twice as wide as it is tall (360x180 for example)

Answer (score 0):

Not really related to computer programing, but here's the answer:

I have a Ricoh Theta S myself and I got the same issue the first time I downloaded a video.

Download the [Theta UVC Blender](https://theta360.com/en/support/download/uvc/) and **drag-and-drop** your video, so the software outputs a "**equirectangular / spherical**" format that you can further upload to Facebook or Youtube.

[image]